# How do I disable a Creatable react-select component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, react-select

I can't figure out what prop to use to disable a Creatable React-select component, is it just missing?

I tried the regular isDisabled prop but was unsuccessful.

```js
<CreatableSelect
  name="serviceOrders"
  className="hide-options"
  value={selectOptions()}
  isDisabled={headerLock}
  onChange={e => {
    this.handleHeaderChange(
      e,
      'serviceOrders',
    );
  }}
  placeholder="Type SO, then press enter..."
  multi
/>
```

I want to disable it for specific situations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `isDisabled` prop for Select components is applicable for **react-select v2** and above. In case you are using a version **1.x.x** please use the `disabled` prop to disable the select component

```
render() {
    return (
      <CreatableSelect
        isClearable
        isDisabled
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        onInputChange={this.handleInputChange}
        options={colourOptions}
      />
    );
  }
```

[Working demo with v2](https://codesandbox.io/s/q7873k1k69)