# Programmatically activate and deactivate "create field" functionality in CreatableSelect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

How do I programmatically activate and deactivate the "create field" functionality in CreatableSelect?

Comment: Please provide example code of CreatableSelect with the "create field" property.  I'm not seeing it in the documentation.

Comment: @ShamarYarde Probably [this](https://react-select.com/creatable).

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How do I disable a Creatable react-select component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54472717/how-do-i-disable-a-creatable-react-select-component)